# how to expand a data table with range from another column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following datatable

```
import pandas as pd
  dt = pd.DataFrame({'id_audience': ['Female 13-17', 'Female 18-20'],
                       'gender': ['female', 'female'],
                       'age_min': [13, 18],
                       'age_max': [17, 20]})
```

I would like to expand this dataframe, to have an extra column (`age`), and `age` should be the range between `age_min` and `age_max`.

The final result would look like this:

```
 dt = pd.DataFrame({'id_audience': ['Female 13-17', 'Female 13-17', 'Female 13-17', 'Female 13-17',
                                   'Female 13-17', 'Female 18-20', 'Female 18-20', 'Female 18-20', ],
                   'gender': ['female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female'],
                   'age_min': [13, 13, 13, 13, 18, 18, 18, 18],
                   'age_max': [17, 17, 17, 17, 20, 20, 20, 20],
                   'age': [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]})
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Row 4 in your output is incorrect, you use the ranges from the second group but the value from the first group

Comment: you are right, i corrected it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter for `age` column:

```
dt = dt.loc[dt.index.repeat(dt['age_max'] - dt['age_min'] + 1)]
dt['age'] = dt['age_min'] + dt.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
dt = dt.reset_index(drop=True)
print (dt)
    id_audience  gender  age_min  age_max  age
0  Female 13-17  female       13       17   13
1  Female 13-17  female       13       17   14
2  Female 13-17  female       13       17   15
3  Female 13-17  female       13       17   16
4  Female 13-17  female       13       17   17
5  Female 18-20  female       18       20   18
6  Female 18-20  female       18       20   19
7  Female 18-20  female       18       20   20
```

Comment: I think it needs a `+1` here : `audiences = audiences.loc[audiences.index.repeat(audiences['e'] - audiences['age']+1)]`, to include the upper bound

Comment: @quant - Thank you, sorry, I miss it.

Answer (score 4):

Also using `explode` like @Wen, but on the min/max age columns to access the ranges directly

---

```
dt.assign(
  age=[np.arange(x, y+1) for x, y in zip(dt['age_min'], dt['age_max'])]
).explode('age').reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
    id_audience  gender  age_min  age_max age
0  Female 13-17  female       13       17  13
1  Female 13-17  female       13       17  14
2  Female 13-17  female       13       17  15
3  Female 13-17  female       13       17  16
4  Female 13-17  female       13       17  17
5  Female 18-20  female       18       20  18
6  Female 18-20  female       18       20  19
7  Female 18-20  female       18       20  20
```

Comment: Nice usage :-) Man

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using new pandas 0.25.0 `explode`

```
s=dt['id_audience'].str.extractall('(\d+)')

dt['age']= [list(range(y.iloc[0,0],y.iloc[1,0]+1)) for x , y in s.astype(int).groupby(level=0)]
dt=dt.explode('age').reset_index(drop=True)
```